# How to increase portability of 7z.exe

Tags: c++, 7zip

I am working on a program that needs to unzip `.zip` files. After trying several different methods to do this, the only one I could find that worked for all my needs is `7z.exe`. It works great as I'm developing since I can just hardcode the location of the executable into the code. However, if anyone else tries to use it, that part won't work. Is there any way to allow them to access this? Thanks!

Comment: You could use lib7zip, I guess.

Comment: 7zip is open-source - feel free to use it:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a compression library (have a look at libarchive: http://www.libarchive.org). If you can't do that, you should ship 7z.exe and its dependencies with your application, putting them in a fixed relative location to your main executable.
Then you get your main executable absolute path using `GetModuleFileName`, strip and combine with the relative path using `PathCchCombine`:

```
char filename[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(NULL,filename,(sizeof(filename))/(sizeof char));
PathCchRemoveFileSpec(filename,(sizeof(filename))/(sizeof char));
PathCchCombine(filename,(sizeof(filename))/(sizeof char),filename,"./7zip/7zip.exe");
//the absolute path of 7z.exe is now in filename
```

Documentation for `GetModuleFileName`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx

`PathCchRemoveFileSpec`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh707092(v=vs.85).aspx

and for `PathCchCombine`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh707085(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I didn't think of the compression library, thanks!